# How to fix - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError). Promise.allSettled is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mobile, node-modules

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIFs1.jpg)
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xzex.jpg)

I have these errors only on some phones when I am testing the mobile functionality. If someone has any idea how to fix it... My node version is 14.10.0 as I understood could be from there, since Promise.allSettled is were handled above version 12.9. When I check the node --version, it is 14.10.0, but my nodejs --version is 10.19.0. The phone is Samsung A3 with android version 8. On huawei Y5 android version 9, there are not any errors, as well on any iPhone, which I have checked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is quite a new addition to `Promise`, so you're just dealing with slightly out-of-date environments. You'll need to polyfill it in the environments where it doesn't exist. Your best bet is to locate a well-maintained polyfill library and use that. (One library is [`core.js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). There was some drama around the availability of the project's originator, but I think that's largely worked out now.)

Comment: Is it possible for the problem to come from the mobile device itself ...

Comment: @DragoJokera - I don't know what you mean. The mobile device will have one or more web browsers on it. Each of those browsers uses a JavaScript engine (one it bundles, or one that comes with the OS -- on iOS it's always the latter, sadly). That JavaScript engine either supports `Promise.allSettled` or doesn't, depending on how old it is.

Comment: I did not know, that my browser is out of date ... so I update Chrome and it is working without throwing this error. Thanks a lot for the support T.J, if it weren't you I would not consider checking that.Thanks again !